# Unable to extract shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat for bz

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, archive, dlib, bzip2

I am trying to run some face frontalization code (using Python3 on Windows10), the code uses opencv and dlib and requires a file called `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`. The code tries to automatically download it and then unzip it but it fails to unzip giving an `unexpected end of archive` error. I tried to use WinRaR to repair the file (which I also tried manualy downloading from http://sourceforge.net/projects/dclib/files/dlib/v18.10/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2) but it says it can only repair .zip and .rar files.

Does anyone know where I can download the uncompressed .dat file from? Or alternatively how I can repair a damaged .bz file in Windows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file is available at 
http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2

I downloaded it and verified that extraction works. The file is smaller than the one used in the previous version, but I think  that is due to improvements.

In case this does not work, let me (or Davis King, who maintains the dlib blog) know so that you can get the uncompressed version.

Comment: My name's not Jim :)

Comment: Very sorry about that m(_ _)m, glad you edited the answer. The other Davis maintains a cat, now that I remember :-p.

Answer (score 3):

Downloading using the CLI is a lot easier.

```
wget http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
```

To decompress the compressed file you just downloaded, use the following command

```
bzip2 -d shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, download `shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat`

from [here](http://dlib.net/files/shape_predictor_68_face_landmarks.dat.bz2). But while downloading, downloads gets failed(i faced this issue). So, if you're also facing the same issue, then i recommend to download it via command-line:

```
$ wget link
```